# Snake game moving issue [JAVA]

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Snake game in Java, as a start I figured out how to get the snake (I have only implemented its head for the moment) move right.
My problem is that I can't get it to move down (the snake should continue going down even if the key is released) when the "down" key is pressed.
Any ideas?

Main code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;    

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        Window window = new Window();
        frame.add(window);

        while(true) {

            window.move();

            Thread.sleep(10);
        }           

    }

}
```

Window code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;    
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class Window extends JPanel {

    public Snake snake = new Snake(this);

    public Window() {

        this.setLayout(null);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g2d) {
        super.paint(g2d);
        snake.paint(g2d);
    }

    public void move() {

        snake.moveRight();

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    snake.setDx(0);

                }
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    snake.moveDown();
                }
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {

            }

        });

        this.repaint();
    }

}
```

Snake code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Snake {

    Window window;

    private int positionX = 0;
    private int positionY = 0;

    private int dx = 1;
    private int dy = 1;

    public Snake(Window window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g2d) {
        g2d.fillRect(positionX, positionY, 20, 20);
    }

    public int getPositionX() {
        return positionX;
    }

    public void setPositionX(int positionX) {
        this.positionX = positionX;
    }

    public int getPositionY() {
        return positionY;
    }

    public void setPositionY(int positionY) {
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }

    public int getDx() {
        return dx;
    }

    public void setDx(int dx) {
        this.dx = dx;
    }

    public int getDy() {
        return dy;
    }

    public void setDy(int dy) {
        this.dy = dy;
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        positionX += dx;
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        positionY += dy;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't post all of your code and say "any ideas?" here. Narrow it down.

Comment: This may not solve your problem... but how many listeners are you adding? With each call of window.move() you are adding a new anonymous listener, or?

Comment: I created an application based on your code and was able to move the snake down.... compared to your original code I only modified the time to sleep and allowed the frame to resize.

Comment: @Stefan Freitag, i want the snake to keep moving even when the DOWN button is released for exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't keep adding a `KeyListener` within in your move method, this will mean that, when you can eventually revive key notifications, you will bombarded with a lot of key events
2. Use the Key Bindings API to over come the focus limitations of `KeyListener`
3. Instead of calling `moveXxx` when a key event occurs, set a flag which indices which direction is active and on each loop of the game cycle, check the state of this flag and call the appropriate method

Answer (score 1):

Currently the snake only moves down because of this code snippet

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
  if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
    snake.moveDown();
  }
}
```

So it moves only down, if the key was released. To have the snake moving down even when the down key is not pressed, I suggest to use an alternative procedure:

- Instead of calling `snake.moveDown()` from inside the listener, I would suggest to update only the delta in x- and/ or y-position inside the listener.
- If i.e. key down is pressed, set dy to 1, if key up is pressed set dy to -1. If left or right key is pressed set dy to 0.
- Do it the same way for x

The `paint` method of the snake could then be used to update/ draw the position of the snakes head.

Answer (score 0):

In your JPanel constructor add:

```
requestFocusInWindow();
```

Also, when the down key is pressed, you are setting dx to 0 when shouldn't it be setting dy to -1?